# Solving a multiplication problem in mips without using MUL command

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

*What I want to do?*

Translate this code without using mul command but only the other possible commands like add, subtruct and logical shift commands.

```
.text
.globl main
main:              # execution starts here
    li $t0,19057        
    li $t1,123               # input data in $t1
    sll $t0,$t0,27
    srl $t0,$t0,26
    mul $t2,$t1,$t0
    li $v0,10   
    syscall
```

The program created must have the same exit as the initial one in $t2 register without using the mul command. **With what commands should I replace the mul command in order to have the same output?**

Note: $t1 register can take any number from 1 to 10.000.000.

Comment: If you need a multiplication `a * b`, you could simply add `a` `b` times to `result` (in a for-loop), but there might be a better bit operation. If `b` happens to be a multiple of `2`, you could simply shift the register to the left.

Comment: That could be a sulotion, however I am not allowed to use loops

Comment: I am allowed to use only add, subtruct and shl commands sadly

Comment: Can you submit the answer using your second suggestion? Thanks, I will pin it. Also, $t1 can change to any number you like.

Comment: Well, my answer doesn't seem to be the best solution, certainly if it's possible with only `add`, `sub` and `shl`, and I think this exercise is about working only with them. (I would need `beq` for the loop to jump out of it.) You will probably get a better solution from people who more experience working on bit level soon ;)

Comment: I thought the loop solution too but sadly it isn't allowed

Comment: Is one of the factors a given constant? Then manually translate the bit pattern of that factor into a sequence of shifts and adds, applied on the other factor. For example, `22*x` can be implemented as `(x<<4)+(x<<2)+(x<<1)`.

Comment: I think you need at least AND and SLTU or some equivalent, as well as ADDU / SUBU, if *both* inputs are runtime-variable.  Otherwise you can break down the set bits in the constant multiplier at "compile" (by hand) time into shifts and adds, like `x*123 = x*128 - x*4 - x` (where powers of 2 can be done by shifting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a loop that simulates how the MUL command works. It then stores the final result in the register $t2.

```
.text
.globl main

main:              # execution starts here
li $t0,19057        
li $t1,123               # input data in $t1

# shift left by 27 bits
sll $t0,$t0,27

# shift right by 26 bits
srl $t0,$t0,26

# initialize result to 0
li $t2, 0

# loop until the multiplier is 0
loop:
beq $t0, $0, end

# add the multiplicand to the result
add $t2, $t2, $t1

# decrement the multiplier
addi $t0, $t0, -1

# jump to the beginning of the loop
j loop

# end of the multiplication
end:

li $v0,10   
syscall
```

Comment: This uses `beq`.  The question said you were only able to use add/sub and shifts, not branches.  If you can, then yeah, multiplication by repeated addition is simple but slow, and shifts are unnecessary for the actual multiplying.